Deregistration in Germany and exceptions for registration
German laws (Section 27, (2)) state that if I move from some apartment where I was registered to another apartment for a period of less than 6 months, then I should not register at the new one.
Now, consider two scenarios when I deregister because I am moving abroad:

I move out of some apartment where I was registered, then stay for 1 month at another apartment in Germany without doing anything, and then deregister.

I move out of an apartment where I was registered, then stay for 1 month somewhere abroad, and then deregister.


Am I right that these scenarios are indistinguishable in practice?

In (2) if you are leaving Germany, why would you wait a month to deregister? They aren't concerned with where you stay when you have left Germany.

My understanding is that the exception doesn't apply if you are registered according to §17(1) and move abroad (i.e., don't have a permanent residence in Germany anymore). The exception is basically applicable for (temporary) secondary residences.

@WeatherVane : for some reason, I need to wait.

Very Related: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/98921/

Abmeldung has to occur between 7 days before and 14 days after!
If you leave Germany, you have a window of 3 weeks to register: 7 days before you vacated the last registred address in Germany and 14 days after. That's what Bundesmeldegesetz § 17 (1) prescribes.
If you stay in Germany for the month, you technically should register to your interim place within 14 days of moving and then deregister in the window for leaving Germany. But 27 does nix the need to register there. So your example 1 is correct - you have to deregister in that timeframe still.
If you stay outside Germany you have to deregister immediately and can not push deregistration to the end of the month. You would violate the law by deregistering 2 weeks after the time window passed. However, that is curable and at worst incurs an administrative fee for such a short duration.

Thanks! But am I right that, in reality, nobody will find out (or the chance is negligible) that I am abroad for this one month? I may always say that I, e.g., visited friends in Germany, which does not require any action in the mentioned 1-month timeframe (according to scenario 1).

I decline to answer that specific request for legal advice
